# Naive bayes classifier with binary data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I am familiar with the understanding of naive bayes classifier with continuous and categorical input with the class variable being binary. But how will it work for binary data input?

```
 Example: (0,0,-), (1,1,+)
```

where the signs are the class variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary data is essentially the same as categorical data, isn't it?

It has categories `0` and `1`.

Comment: then the process is the same?

Comment: Actually binary decisions is the only thing naive bayes does, you reduce everything (categorical, numerical via thresholding) to binary decisions.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of Naive Bayes Classifier:

1. **Gaussian**: It is used in classification and it assumes that features follow a normal distribution.
2. **Multinomial**: It is used for discrete counts. For example, let’s say,  we have a text classification problem. Here we can consider bernoulli trials which is one step further and instead of “word occurring in the document”, we have “count how often word occurs in the document”, you can think of it as “number of times outcome number x_i is observed over the n trials”.
3. **Bernoulli**: The binomial model is useful if your feature vectors are binary (i.e. zeros and ones). One application would be text classification with ‘bag of words’ model where the 1s & 0s are “word occurs in the document” and “word does not occur in the document” respectively.

So here, Bernoulli will work and classify them as 0 or 1.

For details of working, see: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-bernoulli-model-1.html